# attr change on resize does not update

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, attr

I want to change data-width attr depends on (window).width();

here's example [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/ImLjd)

piece of code

```
if ((screen_wd >= 0 ) && (screen_wd <= 460)) {
        $(".fb-like-box").attr({
            "data-width": "440px"
        });

    }
    else if((screen_wd > 460 ) && (screen_wd <= 720)){

        $(".fb-like-box").attr({
            "data-width": "700px"
        });
    } 
    else{

        $(".fb-like-box").attr({
            "data-width": "980px"
        });
    }
```

Rest in example

When u will change window width to for example 400 and "F5" reload it works but it doesnt change on real time resize.

**Thank you for help:)**

Comment: How are you accessing that attribute to know it isn't working?

Comment: you must find some event that get's triggered when a window is resized, and bind your code to it. It won't do the magic automatically.

Comment: it will never work, cause thats an attribute recognized by FB, not real width... you have to change it with css, bye.

Comment: @cfs accesing this attribute is working cuz like i describe when u refresh example it change attr data -width but it doesnt work on resize.

Comment: I did by .fb-like-box iframe but it doesnt change real width when u do responsive css with @media. It change only look but not real width and scrollbar shows original dara-width

Comment: I dont think this will work as you are trying to manipulate content within an iframe which resides on a different server.

Comment: I was thinking the same but hope for some genius brain :)

Comment: :( 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe#comment2590499_364952

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $(window).resize(function(){
    var screen_wd = $(window).width();
    if ((screen_wd >= 0 ) && (screen_wd <= 460)) {
            $(".fb-like-box").attr({
                "data-width": "440px"
            });

        }
        else if((screen_wd > 460 ) && (screen_wd <= 720)){

            $(".fb-like-box").attr({
                "data-width": "700px"
            });
        } 
        else{

            $(".fb-like-box").attr({
                "data-width": "980px"
            });
        }
});
```

But this would only change the attribute 'data-width'. To change real width you need to use `.width()`

Try this:

```
$(".fb-like-box").width(440);
```

Comment: looks like I got what you are trying to ask, hold on, I will make a change

Answer (score 0):

Usually in jQuery HTML data attributes are accessed like this:

```
$(".fb-like-box").data("width", "700px");
```